# Laravel include user's post in hasManyThrough

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a Social Media application where the user's feed is generated through the `hasManyThrough` function on the authenticated user, like this: `Auth::user()->feed`. The function called looks like this:

```
public function feed() {
    $posts = $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Post',
        'App\Follow',
        'follow_by',
        'user_id',
        'id',
        'target_id'
    )->with('user', 'likes', 'comments')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

    return $posts;
}
```

This is done since I want to check which users the authenticated user is following, and then find the posts by these people. However, I also want to include the authenticated user's posts in the query. Previously, I have done this separately through 
`$selfPosts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->with('user', 'likes', 'comments')->get();` and then merged the queries using `$posts = $selfPosts->merge($followPosts)->sortByDesc('id');`.

The problems with merging the queries is many, for example that I cannot use limit nor offset. My question is, how do I include the authenticated user's post in the `feed` function?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Haha, sorry for my newbie mistake. Updated the question. @ColinBarstow

Comment: Are you essentially trying to replicate Facebook's newsfeed, the ability to see your friends posts and your own? Would it not be much easier to just do something along the lines of. Give me all the posts by auth user and auth user friends? That way youre just returning one collection and you can do what you want with it.

Comment: Hmm, not entirely sure what you mean here. I want users to be able to follow each other one way, so that User 1's post can appear in User 2's feed, without User 2's posts appearing in User 1's feed. @ColinBarstow

Comment: So more like twitters structure? The way I said would still apply to this.  Ask your database kindly for all the posts that were written by the authenticated user and any user the authenticated user follows.

Comment: That's what I am trying to a accomplish. Is the hasManyThrough in Auth::user a bad solution for this? If that is the case, what other solutions can I use? @ColinBarstow

Comment: Its not so much a bad solution, it's your solution. It's really difficult to answer without knowing your friends/follows structure and relationships however the way that I would do this.... this is going to be super simple but it's just to explain all you really need to be doing.... I'd build an array; the id's of all the users I follow append my own Id to that array. Then simply ask the database for all the posts written by the users in my array. Obviously using eloquent there wont be any wherein or joins. It will all be defined by relationships

Comment: Take a look at some of the existing friend systems for laravel. There's a few out there and see how they're working behind the scenes. It will give you a good idea of how to implement your own, if not implement the already existing system into your project. 
  https://github.com/AbdullahGhanem/friendship

Comment: Thanks for your help @ColinBarstow. I was overthinking this, a simple solution was definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Colin Barstow suggested in the comments, a simple solution probably is the best solution to this problem, rather than doing a lot of advanced relationships and merging. This was my final solution (thanks Colin):

```
    $DB_follows = Follow::where('follow_by', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $follows = [Auth::user()->id];

    foreach ($DB_follows as $follow) {
        array_push($follows, $follow->target_id);
    }

    $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $follows)->with('user', 'likes', 'comments')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return $posts;
```

Comment: `Post::whereIn('user_id', auth()->user()->follows()->pluck('target_id')->push(auth()->id()))->with('user', 'likes', 'comments')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();` a bit nicer, assuming user hasMany follows relationship